# Looking for multiple terms (sorted by priority)

Tags: vba, excel, find

Would it be possible to use the find method to search for back-up options?

Here's my code right now:

```
 Set foundCell = Cells.Find(What:="RCP 1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            foundCell.Activate
            foundCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("A" & (PLcount + 8)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        Else
            Set foundCell = Cells.Find(What:="RCP- 1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False)
                If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
                    foundCell.Activate
                    foundCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Range("A" & (PLcount + 8)).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                End If
        End If
```

I would like to be able to do something like below. Note the text after .Find(What:=)

```
 Set foundCell = Cells.Find(What:="RCP 1" "RCP- 1" "RCP  1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            foundCell.Activate
            foundCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("A" & (PLcount + 8)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
```

Where the first term is the first priority, the second term is the second priority, the third term is the third priority, etc.

Comment: Just thought of this - is there anything similar to regex in other languages so that I could maybe use "RCP\s1" as a search term? EDIT: just searched it up and found it. I'm still curious about my first question though.

Comment: Hmm I can't really get the regex to work, actually. I tried "RCP\s+1" and "RCP(\s+)1"

Comment: Best you can do with Find would be "RCP*1"

Comment: Smart @TimWilliams. If  you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*EDIT* - there is only limited support for wildcards in `Find()` - you would probably not class it as "regex-level" functionality:

```
* - zero or more characters
? - single character
~ - escapes * or ? if you want to find those literal characters
```

Alternatively can put the `Find` into a separate function:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim foundCell, PLCount As Long

    PLCount = 3
    Set foundCell = FindFirst(Cells, Array("RCP 1", "RCP- 1"))

    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        'no need for any select/activate
        foundCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Range("A" & (PLCount + 8))
    End If

End Sub

'return the first match to a value in the array "arrWhat"
'   Returns Nothing if no match
Function FindFirst(rngWhere, arrWhat) As Range
    Dim v, f As Range
    For Each v In arrWhat
        Set f = rngWhere.Find(what:=v, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next v
    Set FindFirst = f
End Function
```

Comment: I like your answer in the comments!